# I am having error when i run my reactjs project

Tags: reactjs

ERROR: There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"babel-jest": "24.7.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:

/var/www/html/stock-viewer/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 20.0.3)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if /var/www/html/stock-viewer/node_modules/babel-jest is outside your project directory.
    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Try given step into the error.

Comment: delete `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`, run `npm install` again. If that doesn't works use yarn instead of npm.

Comment: So did you read and/or follow any of the advice that they have helpfully given you?

Answer (score 0):

Do an  `npm cache clean --force` and then try Deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`. Then do an `npm install`

Comment: I already tried this but after deleting node_modules and after npm install i get again same error.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions in the error message. If that doesn’t work re-install react-app, and only use one package manager

Answer (score 0):

this problem that happens when want make a create-react app   this depend on some of the package version  that conflict  with the some other version
follow these steps 
delate the node-module file npm unistall node-module or delete forder manual

delete package-lock.json
and delate the package-lock.json and install again 
tell me if it works or not

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Yarn. Delete node_modules and yarn.lock and run npm install.

Comment: But in my ubuntu system npm is not working so i used yarn.

Comment: without npm you can't install yarn..